# Запуск Activity через intent и порядок следования в task и back stack

Tags: android

Activity A вызывает -> Activity B через startActivity.
В notification bar'е висит нотификация, по нажатию на которую запускаю Activity B.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на back запускалась A, как при обычном запуске A->B? (Т.е. симулировать как бы back stack.)

Понятно, что можно написать какой-нибудь костыль, вроде вызова A из B. Но что делать в случае A->B->C->D и вызове интентом D из нотификации, когда приложение вообще не запущено? Может, есть какой-то intent flag. (Документацию читал, пока не понял, возможно ли обойтись флагами.)

**UPD**
Решено с помощью [TaskStackBuilder](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Сомневаюсь, так как никакой флаг не запомнит порядок фрагментов в стэке. Схожую задачу я решал так. В кейсе, если с пушки, приложение не запущено

1) открываю главное активити;
 2) открываю нужный фрагмент;
 3) открываю нужный фрагмент для показа на экране.